# Sql group by with very large join alternative

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table 1**:

```
Itemid   saleid
---------------
53355    23224
33544    33246
53355    33353
43324    33353
```

**Table 2**:

```
Saleid  Rebate
--------------
23224    3000
33246    5000
33353    5555
33353    4444
```

This a simplified table. The issue I have is I want to group by the itemid first and then join table2 saleid. If I do the group by saleid by itself it returns 100,000 rows of data which is fine but if I also group by the saleid to join it I get to millions of rows which makes it not workable for me. Any ideas how I can make this work so I can connect these tables?

So keep in mind the itemid has many items I can group but saleid is not unique so would like to connect this after the group by

Here is a simple query for example that gets me to millions of rows. If it joins after the group by if should still be 100,000 rows of data.

```
select 
    ta.itemid, ta.saleid, sa.itemid
from 
    table1 ta
inner join 
    saleid sa 
where 
    ta.saleitemid = sa.itemid
group by 
    itemid, saleid
```

Comment: show the actual query, but most likely there's nothing you can do. you're getting exactly what you asked for. and note that you don't "group then join". joining is done FIRST, because the grouping cannot be determined until after all relevant row-data is available.

Comment: I provided a simple query above if that helps.

Comment: Can an item id be paired with more than one sale id?

Comment: Well actually. We will likely need to group by the second table also as it could be paired with more than  one salesid in table2 but am happy to get first problem solved first before second problem.

Comment: What result set do you want?  I would expect to see aggregation functions in an aggregation query.

Comment: The result would be that we have the group by the itemid so this would reduce rows to 100k. The field to the right of this would saleitemid (non grouped) we would then join this to table 2 which has other fields to attach to the 100k results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the group by first if you use a subquery and then join that query to table 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT itemid, saleid
FROM Table_1
GROUP BY itemid, saleid) sub
INNER JOIN Table_2
ON sub.saleid = Table_2.saleid
```

Edit: the above query is not working for you based on your comments, so I will try to ask a question that will lead us to what you really want.

Suppose this is table 1:

```
Itemid   saleid
20000    23224
33544    33246
53355    22523
43324    33353
43324    11111
43324    22222
43324    33333
43324    44444
```

And this is table 2:

```
Saleid  Rebate
23224    3000
33246    5000
22523    5555
33353    4444
11111    1111 
22222    2222 
33333    3333
44444    4444
```

***Tell us in the comments what your desired output looks like.***

Additional update: this one shows sum(rebate) per item id:

```
SELECT itemid, SUM(rebate)
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.saleid = t2.saleid
GROUP BY itemid
```

Comment: The issue is that in the first table the group by doesnt work properly when you add saleid to the group by because with the itemid it would normally group down to 100k rows but when you expand the group by to include saleid in the first table it expands to a million for my overall result which isnt what i need.

Comment: So it sounds like itemid can be paired with multiple saleids. In that case, are you trying to reduce your result set so that only one saleid is paired with each itemid? If so, would you like to select the min or max saleid, for example? Which one should be listed?

Comment: Well what im trying to do is group by the first table by itemid which reduces result to 100k and then for these 100k have saleids. At the same time table 2 has multiple saleids which needs to be group by to. Its just linking these to which is the issue.

Comment: I realise that the first table issue is that for each unique itemid i have multiple saleid attach to it. So i have to bring across table2 first for the rebate as suggested which is aggregated. Then I think make I need to make a new table of itemid and rebate only somhhow and group by itemid as a subset. Any ideas on this

Comment: So what you really want is aggregated rebate per itemid? If so, see addition above...

Answer (score 0):

While Group By can allow you to reduce the number of records returned by a query, it is generally used for aggregation (count(), sum(), min(), max() etc.).  Whatever add to the Group By clause will affect the number of records returned as you are making the group by more specific which reduces its ability to group rows together.

It sounds like you have a one to many relationship between your ItemId table and your SalesId table.  So if you select from the Item table and group simply by the ItemId this is a more generic grouping and will reduce the record count down to only those unique ItemIds in the table.  If you include the SalesId in your group by, now you are grouping by only those unique combinations of ItemId AND SalesId which will result in more records.

It doesn't matter at this point if you join the SalesId table into this query or not, you will always get the number of unique ItemIds and SalesIds as long as both are included in the Group By.

Maybe try to restate the results your are trying to get at by giving some more specifics on the data you are querying and we can help you write a more performance-friendly select...

Comment: the result I am trying to achieve is a reduction in the itemID initially as a starting point which would have 100k rows, which then has salesID attached to it (still has 100k rows) which then would provide me a link to table2. In table2 I would need to make the saleids unique and sum the rebate. Then attach this to table 1, so overall we would have 100k rows with itemid, saleid and sum(rebate). That is what im trying to achieve, I don't need to use group by, just want to somehow to get it work, however group by in table1 for both saleids and itemid gives me too many results, into the million.

Comment: Ok so really the aggregation you want to do is in the Sales table to sum the rebate values.  Is this done by Sales ID?  If so you should group records in that table by sales ID and join that to your query of unique ItemId/SalesId combinations.  If Sales ID is the most granular level of data you are trying to return, start by grouping that data down to the individual Sales IDs with their summed Rebate.  Joining that to the Item/Sales combinations should not increase the record count.

Comment: yes that is correct. Aggregation is done in that table2. But somehow need to link it to those 100k rows from table 1, otherwise table1 becomes to big. I need to have a reduced dataset in table1 importantly. The issue im having is table 1, I want to be able to keep the reduced records then attach table 2 for the rebate associated with the saleid. Just cant get the first table 1 working

Comment: I also realise that the first table issue is that for each unique itemid i have multiple saleid attach to it.  So i have to bring across table2 first for the rebate as suggested. Then make a new table of itemid and rebate only and group by itemid. Any ideas on this?